# How to unlink two identical local drives Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning, local

So I recently switched out my HDD for an SSD drive by first cloning the Local Disk (C:) onto the SSD which I gave the name "SSD (S:)." I then booted my pc from the SSD and everything went smoothly. Except that when I went into Quick Access I had 3 drives! I decided to unplug my HDD to try to find out what's the problem, and then Quick Access said I had 2 drives still. One was named Local Disk (C:) which was actually my SSD drive, and the other had a question mark over it and was titled "S:" What the heck! So now my original SSD is named Local Disk (C:) and I have an extraneous drive named "S:"?

So here's what I did to try and get rid of the question mark over the "S:" drive.

I did research and decided to go into cmd (command prompt) and type this code

```
subst S: C:\
```

After doing this, the question mark disappeared and the drive became "Local Drive (S:)" and was an identical copy of Local Drive (C:).

So heres the issue-

I succesfully have switched out my HDD drive for the SSD and things work a lot faster. However, I fear that some file directory's are going to get messed up because now those two Local Disk drives that are identical are also somehow linked, and adding or deleting something from one drive does the same in the other drive. Also, going into task manager or optimize drivers settings, my computer only reads one drive- Local Disk (C:).

So this is what it means- I somehow have an identical cloned Local Disk drive that doesn't actually exist, and is somehow linked to my other drive.

What I want to do is delete that extraneous drive-Local Disk (S:) so that my files do not get corrupted.

Here is a picture of my Disk Management:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdzFY.png)
And here is a picture of the drives in Quick Access:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5NXb.png)

Sorry if this was confusing, but I am lost. Anything will help!

Comment: Please post a screenshot from _Disk Management_ (right-click Windows logo → Disk Management)

Comment: You do realize that Quick Access is merely a dynamic collection of shortcuts…? You can just remove items from there.

Comment: Yes but thats also where my files are stored, and I cant remove the item or it will most likely remove both drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S:` drive seems to exist only because you've `subst`'ed it. The `subst` command is used to make folders appear as drives. I'm not sure why you were thinking `subst` will fix your problem, because its only purpose it *creating* additional drives (and removing ones this command has previously created).

To remove a `subst`'ed drive, use `subst` with the `/D` switch:

```
subst S: /D
```

Comment: I typed in that code and the Local Disk (S:) disappeared, except that now I'm back where I was with a drive with a question mark over it called "S:" in addition to my actual drive.

Comment: @RyanNyberg Have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Yes and the disk with the "?" still appears

Comment: However, now the S: extraneous drive is not appearing on This PC; only in the Quick Access. Trying to open it brings up an error message saying that is unavailable. Does this mean that I can simply remove it from Quick Access since it doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: Also, now under This PC the Documents, Downloads, etc. folders are unavailable because it says that "S:/user/downloads" is unavailable.

Comment: How did you do the cloning part? You can remove S: from quick access. But it seems that there are still some shortcuts pointing at the S: drive for some reason. That would suggest that your system drive was S: at some point and was reassigned to C: later.

Comment: Yes! My orignal SSD was named "S:" drive but after booting Windows from it it reassigned it as "C:" drive and an extra drive with the letter "S:" appeared. Also I cloned it using Macrium Reflect.

Comment: Like I said: You can just remove it. Right-click, “Remove from Quick access” and/or “Unpin from Quick access”.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any ideas better than removing broken shortcuts and replacing them with working ones.

Comment: Ok I think I will just do that, I just wanted to make sure it wouldn't delete all my files! So sorry about the confusion, and thanks so much for the help! I guess I just didn't know that the extraneous "S:" drive was just a broken shortcut.